# When should you pluralize an adjectival noun?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, singular-vs-plural

When should you pluralize an adjectival noun? I am not sure if both are valid, I think both might be valid, so I am wondering if both are ok or not?

So, for example, you may want to say "Apple mountain" or "Apples mountain"? In my opinion, an adjectival noun should never be plural, but I think I saw people use plural before, so I was wondering what's the consensus on this.

Comment: Can you give us any examples of a noun used as an adjective in the plural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, attributive nouns (nouns used as adjectives before another noun) are singular, but there are exceptions. Plural cases and the reasons for them are discussed here:

[English Stack Exchange singular-plural nouns as adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396864/singular-plural-nouns-as-adjectives#397244)

and here:
[English Stack Exchange when are attributive nouns plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural)